# Netty server shutdown exception

Tags: java, netty, tcpserver

I have used to following code to handle server shutdown:

```
public void stop() {
    try {
        this.channelFuture.channel().close();
        this.channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.exceptionStack(e);
    } finally {
        this.bootstrap.config().childGroup().shutdownGracefully(10, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        this.bootstrap.config().group().shutdownGracefully(5, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Sometimes the server shutsdown with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "nioEventLoopGroup-3-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/buffer/PoolArena$1
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.freeChunk(PoolArena.java:293)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$MemoryRegionCache.freeEntry(PoolThreadCache.java:471)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$MemoryRegionCache.free(PoolThreadCache.java:441)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$MemoryRegionCache.free(PoolThreadCache.java:433)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache.free(PoolThreadCache.java:290)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache.free(PoolThreadCache.java:281)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache.free0(PoolThreadCache.java:254)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache.free(PoolThreadCache.java:250)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator$PoolThreadLocalCache.onRemoval(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:431)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator$PoolThreadLocalCache.onRemoval(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:408)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocal.remove(FastThreadLocal.java:226)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocal.removeAll(FastThreadLocal.java:67)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:146)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$1
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 14 more
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/channel/AbstractChannelHandlerContext$13
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.close(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:610)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.close(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:465)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.close(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:964)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(AbstractChannel.java:234)
        at co.gps.smaartly.TrackerServer.stop(TrackerServer.java:59)
        at co.gps.smaartly.ServerManager.stop(ServerManager.java:90)
        at co.gps.smaartly.App$1.run(App.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$13
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
```

I am using netty version 4.1.9.Final on JVM version:

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

On Ubuntu 16.04

Please help me identify the issue here. Let me know if any other details are required.

Comment: Do you use netty-all in your pom dependency?

Comment: When shutting down your server, is the jar still loaded? Some jar deployment systems replace the jar file before shutting down the server. If you have one of the systems, delete the file before writing a new one because on linux this means the old one is still properly loaded

Comment: @DmitrySoroka I have included netty-all in the pom dependency

Comment: @Ferrybig can you please explain this a little more ?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because the jar is unloaded before the shutdown is 100 % complete. `.shutdownGracefully(...)` is asynchronous so you should use `.shutdownGracefully(...).sync()` here.